# how does the immediate constituent analysis of the phrase/sentence 聊斋志异 look like?

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical analysis of this phrase?
What are the parts of speech?
How can the whole sentence be split into smaller logical units?
Is the title itself a real phrase or real sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`聊斋志异` is the name of an ancient novel, which is a collection of nearly 500 mostly supernatural tales written by Pu Songling in Classical Chinese during the early Qing Dynasty.

Source: [Strange Stories from a Chinese Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Stories_from_a_Chinese_Studio)

`聊` means `chat`, `斋` means `room`, and `聊斋` is the name of the author's study room/studio.

`志` means `record`, `异` means `strange things`, `志异` means `to record the strange things`, so `聊斋志异` is a stories' collection about strange things recorded by the author at his study studio named `聊斋`.

BTW: `聊斋志异` could be shortened as `聊斋`.